# Error in Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to create a Makefile using a tut from youtube.
Following the tut, I have got upto this : 
Makefile:

```
COMPILER = g++

LIBS = particle/Source/

INCLUDE_PATH = /particle

SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp)

COMPILER_FLAGS = -w

SOURCE_FILES = Origin.cpp Particle.cpp Texture.cpp

LINKER_FLAGS = -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image.h

executables : 
    mkdir Executables/
    for dir in ${LIBS}; do \
        # cd $$dir  \
        ${COMPILER} ${COMPILER_FLAGS} ${LINKER_FLAGS} ${SRC} -I../;  \
        mv *.o ../../Executables;  \
        cd -;  \
    done

clean:
    rm -rf Executables/
```

My folder structure is :

```
|-- particle
|   |-- Executables
|   |-- Headers
|   |-- Makefile
|   `-- Source
|       |-- Header.h
|       |-- Main.cpp
|       |-- Origin.cpp
|       |-- Origin.h
|       |-- Particle.cpp
|       |-- Particle.h
|       |-- Texture.cpp
|       `-- Texture.h
```

The error I am getting is :

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2_image.h

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

mv: cannot stat ‘*.o’: No such file or directory

I dont know how to correct this as I am completely new to Make (this is my first attempt at it). So please tell me what the error is.
Also pls tell what I should do if I want to keep .h files in the Headers dir .

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the linker was unable to find SDL2_image.h

Do you mean to be linking the header file as a library?  Because that seems more than a little odd.  The linker takes libraries or (if you call it directly) object files, not header files.  Remove SDL2_image.h from your LINKER_FLAGS.  See also the documentation for g++ parameter -l, which is available here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0/gcc_3.html#SEC16

On your second question, header files that are needed by your cpp files are generally included through the CPP files.  Your include directories tell the compiler where to look for other files.  You should make sure your INCLUDE_PATH is set to the root of your project (right now it is set to /particle, but you probably want to set it to the absolute path to particle).  Then you can refer to the header files as follows:

```
#include <Headers/myheader.h>
```